# Mongoose stamped vs. unstamped

Tags: frames

What's the difference between a Mongoose that has logo stamped on frame and a Mongoose with no stamp on it?

Comment: The lack of a stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Newer frames tend to have serial numbers as a sticker rather than a stamp because it is cheaper. Having a stamped serial # or a sticker has almost nothing to do with the quality of the bicycle.

Comment: I was referring to the logo stamp not the serial # stamp.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the head-tube badge?  My mongoose road bike has a black and chrome curved thing which stands about 2mm out from the red paint and metal of head tube.  [image]

GUESS: The road bikes are trying to look like old-school bikes with decals, whereas mountain bikes don't care so much.

To be honest head tube badges don't do anything for you or your bike, other than perhaps a bit of paint / stone chip protection.